# Corrupted macOS partition after GParted

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, unix, dual-boot

I followed a [tutorial](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-on-mac-hardware) to create dual boot with macOS Sierra 10.12 and Kali-Linux 2.0.

I created a bootable USB drive and booted on a Kali-Linux live session in order to use GParted and resize my macOS Partition.

I selected the macOS partition and resized it from 239 GB to 200 GB. I got 2 partitions, with the 39 GB partition formatted to "unallocated".

But now when I try to boot to macOS, I get the Apple logo then a white cross and can't boot to macOS.

I tried to boot in Recovery HD by holding <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, then I tried to use S.O.S. but it says I need an Assistant recovery disk. We can create a USB recovery disk by plugging in a USB drive to our MacBook then use the assistant to create a bootable USB drive which can repair disks, but like I said my MacBook can't boot on macOS, so I can't create it...
Is there a way to download the iso of the recovery USB drive directly to create my own recovery USB drive from it?

I read somewhere that I need to rewrite the corrects boot codes and my data isn't lost. Is that true?

What do you think I can do?

**Edit:**
Here is the output of diskutil/gpt:

[image: Terminal]

(Sorry for the low compression rate I haven't 10 reputation to post more than 2 pics)

I didn't expect the result of Diskutil. So much partition is normal ?

**Edit2**:

Here is the other screen I had after write commands :

[image: Terminal2]

**Edit 3**

[image: Last verify]

Comment: Did you install rEFInd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GParted didn't really create unallocated disk space. Instead the MBR got bogus. The CoreStorage LVG and all subsequent containers got corrupted also, because the whole stack wasn't resized as required. Usually - in macOS - the whole stack is resized with the command `diskutil cs resizeStack ...`. As far as I can say from remote, the ending boundary of the second partition was simply moved to lower block numbers which usually works with normal HFS+ volumes in GParted but not in this case with a CoreStorage stack. Fortunately some *invisible* data structures of the CS stack weren't overwritten.

Additionally the recovery partition wasn't moved properly. But this a different problem.

Instead of the MBR you should have a pMBR. After removing the bogus MBR you have to destroy and recreate the GUID partition table:

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal in the menubar Utilities -> Terminal
- Get an overview (especially the *gpt* command is important!):

  ```
  diskutil list
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```
- Unmount disk0:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- Delete the MBR:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0 bs=512 count=1
  ```
- Destroy the GUID partition table and create a new one (this also creates a fresh pMBR):

  ```
  gpt destroy disk0
  gpt create -f disk0
  ```
- Rebuild all previous GUID partitions:

  ```
  gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
  gpt add -i 3 -b 488965176 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 409602008 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```

  If you get a resource busy error after one of the steps, just unmount disk0 again with

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```

Check the disk with `diskutil verifyDisk disk0` afterwards.

Enter `diskutil cs list` and check if all four CoreStorage containers appear: a Logical Volume Group, a Physical Volume and Logical Volume Family and a Logical Volume.

With the UUID of the Logical Volume mount the LV:

Example:

```
    +-> Logical Volume 9A7B21AA-F9FE-4E65-8C7E-ED2A73744C15
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Disk:                  disk17
        Status:                Online
```

Then use:

```
diskutil mount 9A7B21AA-F9FE-4E65-8C7E-ED2A73744C15
```

Then after getting the disk identifier of the mounted LV with `diskutil list` verify the volume:

```
diskutil verifyVolume disk17 # probably it's disk17, disk16 or disk18
```

Below I assume the disk identifier is disk17

---

If the Logical Volume Family and the Logical Volume don't appear try the following:

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal in the menubar Utilities -> Terminal
- Get an overview (especially the *gpt* command is important!):

  ```
  diskutil list
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```
- Unmount disk0:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- Remove the current partition entry for the second partition:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 2 disk0
  ```
- Add a new "expanded" second partition entry:

  ```
  gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 488555536 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```
- Then repeat all verify steps:

  Check the disk with `diskutil verifyDisk disk0` afterwards.

  Enter `diskutil cs list` and check if all four CoreStorage containers appear: a Logical Volume Group, a Physical Volume and Logical Volume Family and a Logical Volume.

  With the UUID of the Logical Volume mount the LV:

  Example:

  ```
      +-> Logical Volume 9A7B21AA-F9FE-4E65-8C7E-ED2A73744C15
          ---------------------------------------------------
          Disk:                  disk17
          Status:                Online
  ```

  Then use:

  ```
  diskutil mount 9A7B21AA-F9FE-4E65-8C7E-ED2A73744C15
  ```

  Then after getting the disk identifier of the mounted LV with `diskutil list` verify the volume:

  ```
  diskutil verifyVolume disk17 # probably it's disk16, disk17 or disk18
  ```

  If you get errors backup the data or the whole partition to an external volume then repair the volume with `diskutil repairVolume disk17`.

  One possibility to backup the data is `dd`. Attach a HFS+ formatted drive with at least 250 GB free space. Get the path to the external volume with `ls /Volumes`. Then unmount disk17 and disk0 with `diskutil umountDisk disk17` and `diskutil umountDisk disk0`.

  Then clone the partition to a file:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/disk0s2 of=/Volumes/ExternalDriveName/disk0s2.rawdevice bs=4m
  ```

  If the volume name contains spaces, escape the spaces with backslashes: `...of=/Volumes/ExternalDriveName\ With\ Spaces/disk0s2.rawdevice...`.

  You can also use `asr` to restore the partition to another disk (as a temporary "backup"). Check `man asr`.

Comment: When I used diskutil verifyDisk, I get warned of errors which may prevent boot. I tried to boot and it doesn't works (but I have a mBPR now). But the diskutil cs list give me one logical Volume group, and under it only one physical Volume. I haven't the four volumes

Comment: Did I lost my datas ?

Comment: Ok I get back all the 4 volumes. Then I did the mount, all worked great, but the last diskutil verifyVolume gave me errors, I update my first post

Comment: I edited my first post

Comment: How can I backup it ? If I repair it with this command, I'll lost my data ?

Comment: Yes I have, but if I clone corrupted part, I'll backup corrupted data no ?

Comment: I'm not able to delete my comments... How can I clone it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and all your answers, I really appreciated all your work.

Comment: I don't understand why, because I got the error while the verifyvolume, but I could boot on Mac OS !!! THANKS A LOT !

Comment: @MaximeOzenne It will boot - that's not the problem. Some [internal data of the volume structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Design) is corrupted or false though. This should be repaired before using the volume!

Comment: I was able to use the disk utility, I used the SOS assistant and it said that MAcintosh HD was damaged. I rebooted on the recovery and re-used the SOS assistant again and again until it said me that the disk is OK. Finally I run a terminal and used diskutil cs list to get the disk identifier of LV (it was disk1) then I run diskutil verifyVolume disk1. I finally was happy to see that my LV is repaired ! my mac seems to works great now ! A huge thanks for all your help you saved me !!

Comment: It always stuns me when a long answer like this has one and only one person that's willing to +1 - however, the OP ticking the answered check is most awesome - that's so much better for the site in general.

Comment: @bmike Thanx! ;-) I think that's a general problem here. It's the threshold between "personal" troubleshooting **and** a more or less generic answer to a more or less generic question. I think at least David Anderson has the same problem with all his slightly different Boot Camp q&a. I'm still thinking about posting a question in meta addressing this. Another good example is this question: [BootCamp Partition Error!! Help. Deleted EFI Partition](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256208/bootcamp-partition-error-help-deleted-efi-partition). I could only solve it via TeamViewer.

Comment: your tips will be apreciated https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296151/recover-files-from-corrupted-external-usb-hd-macos-sierra