# Prohibitory sign after using SuperDuper!; MacBook Pro can no longer boot from MacOS X partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition

This is going to be a long story, but please bear with me...

I'm trying to recover a MacOS X partition that got lost on my Seagate HD.  This HD was dual booted using BootCamp with Windows 10.  I originally had Linux on this HD too, but eventually deleted it and used BootCamp to put on a Windows 10 install. (This is all on a late 2011 MacBook Pro).  I was actually trying to migrate everything over to a solid state drive by using SuperDuper! and Winclone, but something went wrong in the whole process, and all of a sudden I couldn't boot into the MacOS operating system any longer (gave the prohibitory sign).  To make things worse, the system couldn't actually find the MacOS partition either.

So I used Apple's internet recovery to at least get a bootable MacOS X going and put the SSD into the MacBook Pro.  I then put the Seagate HD into a Sabrent external USB adaptor so I could see what was going on.  After booting into MacOS and running terminal, I see this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh SSD           499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            336.8 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                110.0 GB   disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS                        +336.5 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2
                                 0F8A5999-AA3A-42E3-AB53-260295D99FA1
                                 Unencrypted
```

So you can see that it knows the MacOS partition is there (disk1s2), but it won't mount, DiskUtility has no idea what is on the disk (it's greyed out), and I obviously can't browse into it to get any files.  I don't know why it lists an external virtual volume as well...this seems to be the MacOS partition as well - i.e. it looks like disk2 is the same as disk1s2.  I ran First Aid on it through DiskUtility, but got:

```
File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed.
```

If you try and run DiskUtility through Recovery on the entire drive, it says something's wrong and that it may be corrupt.

Using the command fdisk /dev/disk1 gives:

```
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 60801/255/63 [976773168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AC 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  657891312] <Unknown ID>
 3: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 658300952 -    1269536] Darwin Boot 
*4: 0C 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 659570688 -  214843392] Win95 FAT32L
```

Using the command gpt -r show disk1 gives:

```
gpt show: disk1: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  657891312      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  658300952    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  659570488        200         
  659570688  214843392      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  874414080  102359055         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

I think this might be similar to an issue someone was having here:

[Prohibitory sign on boot after Sierra update, can't mount disk anymore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289225/prohibitory-sign-on-boot-after-sierra-update-cant-mount-disk-anymore)

but I'm not sure, so I thought I'd post this.

Any help that anyone can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, @kanomath.  I installed High Sierra on the SSD.  How can you tell it's the MBR?  Is it because of the gpt output?

Comment: No.  I updated it to Mojave.

Comment: Mojave usually doesn't support MacBook Pro 2011 (early & late)! So it's difficult to say how a High Sierra boot volume handles your patched Mojave boot volume. First I thought it's the MBR on the external disk (macOS & Bootcamp)

Comment: I understand and I've thought about that, but whenever I recount the events, even when the Seagate was the only HD when everything happened, the system wasn't even seeing the OS X partition as bootable then.  So either way, there's an issue I hope can be solved.  Would using the gpt command in terminal to delete the partition and then re-assign it with the same partition type GUID write the correct information into the MBR?  I'm open to doing a TeamViewer session if you are!  I'll be travelling Tuesday and Wednesday, so maybe we can coordinate something for later in the week?  Let me know.

Comment: Where are you right now (time zone)? I'm living in Berlin (MESZ=GMT+2).

Comment: I'm in Chicago, IL, USA...which is GMT-6 I believe.

Comment: It's CDT = GMT-5 which means a ∂ of 7 hours. We may have a session now or later this day or week. I'm up until maybe 9pm your time today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98462/discussion-between-dave-and-klanomath).