# Unable to find my Mac OS operating system in /dev/disk0

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I have issues similar to this case :

[Accidently deleted some small sized partitions when installing WIndows(Bootcamp). OSX Partition wont boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167380/accidently-deleted-some-small-sized-partitions-when-installing-windowsbootcamp)

I was installing Windows 10 into my laptop using bootcamp and deleted some partitions which I thought it was unnecessary. And now the only option I have is to boot into Windows OS. I followed the method as shown in the link above but apparently my Mac OS is not inside the disk0, I am very sure that I did not delete the Mac OS and I only delete the small partitions. I am currently running Mac OS Sierra. Is it because it is hidden? I have really important unsaved documents inside my operating system and I would be really glad if someone could offer me some help!

Sorry I am a complete beginner and have no idea how to solve this problem.

Here I attach with the screenshot I took:

[image]

Comment: Please add the output of  `gpt -r show disk0` to your question.

Answer (score -1):

According to your screenshot, it looks like you deleted your main OS X partition and the recovery partition. You may very well have destroyed your data.

There is a glimmer of hope though. The numbers don't add up. It's a 250GB drive but the Windows partition is only 70GB. There's ~180GB of space unaccounted for, which might be the partitions you deleted. It's tough to say without knowing the exact steps you took.

You can try to use a partition recovery program like TestDisk to get them back.

I could tell you more of you post a screenshot of the output of the following command:

```
sudo gpt show /dev/disk0
```

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` when running from the Recovery HD.

Comment: Please comment the question instead of asking for screenshots **in your answer**!

Comment: Dear all, I contacted apple support and they confirmed that I have accidentally deleted my hard disk. I did a clean restore and lost all my data == Thanks for all your help!